# Jest: Invalid hook call when rendering react component that uses hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm facing a wierd issue and tried for hours searching the web and using GPT to may solve this. I just finished setting up jest and testing-library in a react application inside lerna monorepo. after I managed to get it to work, when I try to test some login component, I'm getting this error:

the test file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
import Login from '../src/components/Login';

describe("login", () => {
    test("login form should be in the document", () => {
        const component = render(<div><Login/></div>);
    });
});
```

the error that shows the hook inside the Login component:

```
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
    1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
    2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
    3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
    See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

      15 | const Login = ({ theme, title = "Login", onSuccessCallback }) => {
      16 |     const isDark = theme === "dark"
    > 17 |     const [ isPasswordVisible, setIsPasswordVisible ] = useState(false);
```

any ideas why this happens? the app is working fine with no issues or warnings, so it's not a react issue, duplicated versions or what so ever.

Appreciate your help!

tried to test a login component in a react app with jest, and got an error of invalid use of react hooks.

Comment: If it's not a "normal" invalid hook call (where you're calling a hook somewhere you're not supposed to), and the versions aren't mismatched (check package.json), then it probably actually is the more than one copy of React issue, but hard to debug that based on just the info in this question. Search around for that specific issue and see if you can find something that helps. Might have to do with how you're bundling things when you build your app. For example, if you have two different libraries both using React, they should have it as a peer dependency instead of both bundling it themselves.

Comment: @cjl750 only root level uses react, all others ha in as a peer dependency. If I had this issue than my app won't work, no?

Comment: It's also possible that the Jest setup isn't quite the same as how the app actually runs. You can try rendering a super simple component in the Jest test to see if the error persists (in which case the problem is something outside the Login component). If you do that and figure out that the problem _is_ with the Login component, but it works fine in your app, then you have to look at what things are maybe missing in your Jest setup. Maybe Login needs access to some context provider higher up the tree that you need to mock (just an example).

Comment: @cjl750 all components that uses hooks are failing. those are isolated components thaat has no dependencies or context needed. the components that does not use hooks are woking and tests are passing.